# how to display nested items using fetchData method in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm able to fetch the data but not sure how to map nested items
data looks like that

```
{"id":3,
      "brands":[{"id":6,"products":[],    
                 "title":"Lenovo",
                 "image":"/img.png",
                 "timestamp":"2022-02-07T15:11:36.059719+05:30",
                 "updated":"2022-02-07T15:11:36.059719+05:30",
                 "category":3}],
"title":"Laptop",
"image":"/img.png",
"timestamp":"2022-01-30T23:18:14.124583+05:30",
"updated":"2022-01-30T23:18:14.124583+05:30"}
```

I'm using following method to do this.

```
const CategoriesToBrands = ({ match }) => {
  const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState({});
  const { id } = useParams();
  async function fetchData() {
    const data  = await fetch("/api/v1/categories/nested/" + id);
    data.json()
      .then(data => setItems(data))
      .catch(data => setErrors(data));
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(items)}</div>
      <hr />
        {items.title}
      <hr />
      <div>Has error: {JSON.stringify(hasError)}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default CategoriesToBrands;
```

I also tried multiple method suggested on stack overflow to map the items but no one seems to be working . or they are using another method . there can be multiple number of items in brands [] and i want to display each one of them for now there is one.. So what would be the syntax or method to map them properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `brands` array inside your main object fetched by async request. It means you should to get brands by `items.brands`. Something like that:

```js
const CategoriesToBrands = ({ match }) => {
  const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState({});
  const { id } = useParams();
  async function fetchData() {
    const data  = await fetch("/api/v1/categories/nested/" + id);
    data.json()
      .then(data => setItems(data))
      .catch(data => setErrors(data));
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(items)}</div>
      <hr />
        {items.title}
      <hr />
      {items.brands ? items.brands.map(brand => (
         <div key={brand.id}>brand id: {brand.id}</div>
      )) : null}
      <div>Has error: {JSON.stringify(hasError)}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default CategoriesToBrands;
```

The good idea is also changing the name of your const `[items, setItems] = useState({});`. In your case you are fetching **one item**, not multiple (I assume this fact by your `id` variable). So the name like `item, setItem` sounds better.

Comment: thanks it seems to be working now .

Comment: Nice to be able to help!